# Can I programmatically connect to a different WCF endpoint in my web service?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

Right now, I have a WCF web service on one machine that is connected to a WCF windows service on another machine that does all the data processing. The web service directly references the windows service and all of the configuration info is set in the web and app.config files.

In order to make this scalable, I want the web service to be able to connect to multiple WCF windows services on separate machines. For example, clients 1 to 3 would have all their data processing handled on one windows service/machine while clients 4 to 6 would have theirs on a separate windows service/machine.

I'm thinking of implementing it like this; Have a SQL database storing the WCF endpoints to a clientID, the web service takes in the clientID and gets a WCF endpoint in return, and then the web service connects to that specific windows service with that WCF endpoint.

Is this doable, or is there a better way to handle this? I haven't had much WCF experience so I could be on the wrong track here.

Thanks.

Comment: This is doable.  You can specify the URL (endpoint) of the webservice when you create the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF supports both administrative client configuration (through config file) and programmatic client configuration. You need the second one.

Here is example of programmatic configuration:

```
Binding wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/SomeService");
SomeServiceClient proxy = new SomeServiceClient(wsBinding, endpointAddress);

proxy.SomeMethod();

proxy.Close();
```

With program configuration through `Binding` and `EndpointAddress` classes you could achieve the same flexibility as with config files.

For further help, see:

[Binding Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding(v=vs.110).aspx)

[EndpointAddress Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.endpointaddress(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ClientBase Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thank you for the response I will check out those links